# Local Notification is firing, but not visible. (iOS)

Tags: ios, notifications, local, uilocalnotification

I am using the following code to make a local notification:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30]; //itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = parentController.activeAssignment.notes;
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

I have checked using the method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

that the notification is firing, but is not showing up on my screen when the app is running in the background.

Comment: Have you double checked to make sure `parentController.activeAssignment.notes` is not nil or an empty string? If the notification is firing, but not displaying, maybe it's because it has nothing to display.

Comment: @SeanT Yeah, I am able to display it in a UIAlertView.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to check is if for some reason your app has notifications turned off in the Notifications section of the Settings app.

Comment: I just checked that and for some reason it is not showing up there, but it was 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Are you testing it on a device or in the simulator? I'm not sure why it wouldn't show up there, but I would recommend deleting the app and then reinstalling it through Xcode and then check if it shows up in settings.

Comment: Hmm it still isn't there. And i'm using my phone.

Comment: @PeterSauer I'm having the same problem as you had. Do you remember by any chance if you found a solution?